# Android Studio Flamingo - Palette tool missing

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-2.3, android-studio-flamingo

I am a newbie in android app development. I took a course online in which they are using Android Studio 2.3.3. They are using Component tree and Palette alot. I have spent hours to find it, but I couldn't. Can someone please help me locate it? or, Have they removed it completely?

Tried searching on chatgpt, google and reditt. But there was very limited information about this issue, maybe because flamingo is the newest version out. I was able to locate Component tree under layout inspection tab, however some of its content was different from they show in the video.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.